# Chart.JS Bar Chart Throwing Error About Missing )

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, chart.js

I am in need of a way to generate a bar chart - and I for some reason am having a world of a time to get this syntax proper.  I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

On this line `label: 'Dollar Values',`

Why is the dev console giving me this error when I have looked at everything and I see that all of my parens have a closing tag.  How should this be altered in order to execute successfully?

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvasone').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    data: {
        type: 'bar',
        labels: yoylabels,
        datasets: [{
                label: 'Dollar Values',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 129, 214, 0.8)',
                data: vals
            }]
    },
    options: {
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function (t, d) {
                        var xLabel = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].label;
                        var yLabel = t.yLabel >= 1000 ? '$' + t.yLabel.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") : '$' + t.yLabel;
                        return xLabel + ': ' + yLabel;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            display: false,
            position: 'top',
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        callback: function (value, index, values) {
                            if (parseInt(value) >= 1000) {
                                return '$' + value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                            } else {
                                return '$' + value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }]
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put your snipppet in http://jshint.com/ and I think you literally just need to remove the last curly brace - try the following:

**Edit** this snippet won't actually run, I mean try this adjustment.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvasone').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    data: {
        type: 'bar',
        labels: yoylabels,
        datasets: [{
                label: 'Dollar Values',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 129, 214, 0.8)',
                data: vals
            }]
    },
    options: {
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function (t, d) {
                        var xLabel = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].label;
                        var yLabel = t.yLabel >= 1000 ? '$' + t.yLabel.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") : '$' + t.yLabel;
                        return xLabel + ': ' + yLabel;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            display: false,
            position: 'top',
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        callback: function (value, index, values) {
                            if (parseInt(value) >= 1000) {
                                return '$' + value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                            } else {
                                return '$' + value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }]
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: If I run your snippet I get an error.  Should I run it in my IDE not Stack Overflow?

Comment: the snippet wont run here because it doesn't have the full context of the rest of your code, i was just using a snippet for syntax highlighting. Try making that edit in your code and seeing if ti works?

Comment: great stuff! some times you just need another pair of eyes on these things, right? feel free to accept this if it solves your problem ;)